# How to manipulate coordinates of the drag image during drag move

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, drag-and-drop

in some cases I use a specific drag image for some drag'n'drop operations in my application. The image can also be placed when adding relativ to the mouse cursor. That works quite fine.
Is it also possible to manipulate the coordinates of the drag image during drag move? In my case the x ccordinate of the drag image must be fixed and only the y coordinate can change so the drag image can only moved up and down.
So far I found no possibilities to handle that.

Thanks a lot, Szdnez

Comment: You tagged your question as _gwt_.  Do you want to know how to do this in GWT or javascript?

Comment: See my first comment at Rubens answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate it using the HTML 5 drag an drop API, but you can do it with some libraries as the [jquery ui draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).
There's also a ton of libraries out there with the same intent. :)

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({axis: 'x'});
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p><b>[DRAG ME]</b><p>
  <p>Drag fixed to the x axis</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Does jquery use mouse events to implement drag'n'drop? Because I am using Vaadin and GWT/JavaScript and want to make the Vaadin Grid (Vaadin 8.1) draggable. If I use the standard Vaadin way HTML5 drag'n'drop is used. I also had the same problem with a canvas. For that I used the lib gwtdnd (uses mouse events) and it works fine. But the lib is not usable for the grid. I suppose the grid catches a lot of mouse events so the lib is not informed and can not work correctly.

Comment: If you have any problems, simply wrap your grid in a container <div> and stop the events triggered from this div of being bubbled up. You can just use the method ["stopPropagation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) of the event object